# Jmeter regular expression to exclude string/word

Tags: regex, jmeter, response

Is there's a way to extract and exclude the entire line that has "**ls Cannot access**" Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Sample Response:

10.179.10.12 ls: cannot access /home/bushido/components/pkg-build-ng/version/2-328/_MANIFEST.linux: No such file or directory
10.179.10.13 ls: cannot access /home/bushido/components/pkg-build-ng/version/2-328/_MANIFEST.linux: No such file or directory
10.179.10.14 /home/bushido/components/pkg-build-ng/version/2-328/_MANIFEST.linux

[image]

Expected Result:

10.179.10.14 /home/bushido/components/pkg-build-ng/version/2-328/_MANIFEST.linux

[image]

Note: The IP address are dynamic

Comment: Thank you so much, for your prompt response, if you have a spare time can you also try to visit my inquiry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986761/jmeter-json-response-converting-to-an-array-with-request-modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?m)^(?!.*ls: cannot access)(.+)
```

Details:

- `(?m)` - multiline inline flag to make `^` match start of a  line, not just start of a string
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!.*ls: cannot access)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `ls: cannot access` string
- `(.+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the whole line).