# Jmeter JSON response converting to an Array with request modification

Tags: arrays, json, api, jmeter, response

Hello I want to simulate this scenario , example if  I got this response below, I want to use that on my succeeding request. The **appid** will be use for **key** and **Role** to **value** parameter. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Request:

```
[{
    "appid": "4a157c66-4965-30b2-af47-7dc68651c350",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.235",
    "Role" : "AD SERVER"}, 
{
    "appid": "ba3fe4b4-1307-38e4-ace4-1636f8ffef3e",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.236",
    "Role" : "TESTING SERVER"
}, {
    "appid": "29b59fbb-ea93-3adf-ba9a-fd353abaac21",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.237",
    "Role": "UAT SERVER"
}]
```

Response Screenshot:

[image]

Expected  Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JSON JMSEPath extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to extract values and transform the keys. [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

```
[].{Key:Role,Value:orgId}
```

[image]

Following demonstrate the testing the `JSON JMESPath Query` in the View Results Tree.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution with Groovy.

```
String response = """
[{
    "appid": "4a157c66-4965-30b2-af47-7dc68651c350",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.235",
    "Role" : "AD SERVER"}, 
{
    "appid": "ba3fe4b4-1307-38e4-ace4-1636f8ffef3e",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.236",
    "Role" : "TESTING SERVER"
}, {
    "appid": "29b59fbb-ea93-3adf-ba9a-fd353abaac21",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.237",
    "Role": "UAT SERVER"
}]
"""


String request = response.replace("appid", "key")
        .replace("Role", "value")
        .replaceAll("\"orgId\":\\s?\".*\",\n", "")
        .replaceAll("\"ipAddress\":\\s?\".*\",\n", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another solution.
There should be a better way to replace the keys

```
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String response = """
[{
    "appid": "4a157c66-4965-30b2-af47-7dc68651c350",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.235",
    "Role" : "AD SERVER"}, 
{
    "appid": "ba3fe4b4-1307-38e4-ace4-1636f8ffef3e",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.236",
    "Role" : "TESTING SERVER"
}, {
    "appid": "29b59fbb-ea93-3adf-ba9a-fd353abaac21",
    "orgId": "205d64ff-9b58-3aad-bf48-29ec41dd4ef0",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.100.237",
    "Role": "UAT SERVER"
}]
"""
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def responseJSON = jsonSlurper.parseText(response)

def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
        .excludeNulls()
        .excludeFieldsByName('orgId', 'ipAddress')
        .build()

String request = generator.toJson(responseJSON)
request =JsonOutput.prettyPrint(request)
request = request.replace("appid", "key")
.replace("Role","value")

println(request)
```